# C++ error: Cannot covert argument 2 from 'char' to char[]'

Tags: c++

I have been getting this error in Visual studio 2017:

> error C2664: 'void Employee::assignDetails(int,char [],double)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'const char [6]' to 'char []'
>
> note: Conversion from string literal loses const qualifier (see /Zc:strictStrings)

I don't get what's wrong.
This is the code:

```
class Employee
{
public:
    void assignDetails(int pempno, char pname[], double pbasicSal);
};

void Employee::assignDetails(int pempno, char pname[], double pbasicSal)
{
}

int main()
{
    Employee emp1;

    emp1.assignDetails(10, "Wimal", 50000);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just change it to `const char* pname`. Better still uses `std::string`.

Comment: Is that really the error you get? Verbatim?

Comment: It works . Thank you Paul Rooney.

Comment: Yes it is the error I get StoryTeller.

Comment: `char pname[]` is non-const. `"Wimal"` is `const` (a `const char[6]` which decays to `const char*`). Assigning `const char*` to `char*` is probably the problem for compiler.

Answer (score 1):

The `"Wimal"` string literal has the type `const char [6]` but your method takes the type `char[]`.

The `const` is important and tells the compiler it isn't allowed to modify the string. You need to change the signature of your method to `const char[]`.

Unless you really know what you are doing you should always use `std::string` instead of raw character arrays. String literals are automatically convertible to `std::string`. You can just use the following code to copy a string:

```
std::string string1 = "Wimal";
std::string string2 = string1;
```

This is much simpler and safer than the c string equivalent:

```
const char* string1 = "Wimal";
char* string2 = (char*)malloc(strlen("Wimal"));
strcpy(string2, string1); // will produce undefined behaviour if string2 is too small
free(string2); // easy to forget and causes memory leaks
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that when you make a C++ string constant e.g.: `"Wimal"` it's a `const char *`.

So when you call your function, this can't be converted to a `char[]` type parameter.
Convert the parameter to `const char *`, and it will work

```
void Employee::assignDetails(int pempno, const char *pname, double pbasicSal)
{
}
```